# borrador vs boceto

Tags: sinónimos, diferencias-entre-palabras

¿Hay alguna diferencia de significado o de uso entre "boceto" y "borrador" cuando se refieren a una versión inicial/provisoria de algo? Las definiciones relevantes en el DLE me parecen idénticas:

> [boceto](https://dle.rae.es/boceto)
> 1. m. Proyecto o apunte general previo a la ejecución de una obra artística.
> 2. m. Esquema o proyecto en que se bosqueja cualquier obra.

> [borrador](https://dle.rae.es/borrador)
> 2. m. Texto provisional susceptible de modificación y desarrollo.
> 3. m. Boceto o primeras pruebas de un dibujo.

Ejemplos:

- El escritor está escribiendo un borrador/boceto de su nuevo libro.
- El desarrollador de software dibujó un borrador/boceto de la nueva arquitectura en la pizarra.
- Todos los pintores hacen un borrador/boceto en lápiz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dados los extractos que incluyes parece claro que ambas palabras son sinónimas, pero yo personalmente empleo más **boceto** cuando está relacionado con un dibujo o pintura y **borrador** cuando se trata de un texto.

El DLE no destaca esta diferenciación pero sí lo hace el Diccionario Oxford, donde la relación entre ambos términos se omite y **borrador** se limita a los textos.

[**boceto**](https://www.lexico.com/es/definicion/boceto)

> 1 Estudio o ensayo en el que se trazan las líneas generales y la
> composición que tendrá una pintura.
>  2 Esquema o proyecto que contiene
> solamente los rasgos principales de una obra artística o técnica.

[**borrador**](https://www.lexico.com/es/definicion/borrador)

> 2 Redacción provisoria de un escrito, en la cual se hacen las
> correcciones necesarias para la redacción definitiva.

Por tanto en las frases que indicas yo emplearía:

- El escritor está terminando el *borrador* de su nuevo libro.
- El desarrollador de software dibujó un *boceto* de la nueva arquitectura
  en la pizarra.
- Todos los pintores hacen un *boceto* en lápiz.

He cambiado "escribiendo" por "terminando" en la primera frase porque quedaba algo redundante.

Nótese también que el borrador de un libro da la sensación de ser algo más completo que un mero boceto. En la definición de arriba podemos observar que al borrador parece faltarle únicamente una fase de corrección para dar por finalizado el libro. Corregir lo que ya hay hecho (borrador) más que completar y expandir el contenido bosquejado al trazar las líneas generales (boceto).

De todas formas, insisto en que lo que expongo son apreciaciones subjetivas, más o menos respaldadas por el Diccionario Oxford. Creo que, como indica el DLE, ambas palabras pueden usarse indistintamente.

Por cierto, como desarrollador de software, yo emplearía la palabra **esquema** en la segunda frase, más que *boceto*. Recurro de nuevo al Diccionario Oxford porque el DLE no acaba de darme la definición que esperaba.

[**esquema**](https://www.lexico.com/es/definicion/esquema)

> Exposición ordenada de los puntos o cuestiones esenciales de un asunto
> o materia; en especial la escrita en que dichos puntos se relacionan
> con líneas, números u otros signos gráficos para indicar su
> interdependencia.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con tus apreciaciones subjetivas (y al fin y al cabo ningún diccionario puede capturar todos los matices de una palabra). De hecho, si escucho decir *el boceto de un libro*, lo primero que me viene a la mente es que se trata de un libro de ilustraciones.